# force link to go to top of page

Tags: html, anchor, hyperlink

i have a site with multiple pages inside a single index.html.

the menu elements call for these pages using a path "#!/..."

```
<nav class="menu">
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li id="item1"><span></span><a "javascript:void(0)" href="#!/">home</a></li>
                    <li id="item2"><span></span><a href="#!/page_about">about us</a></li>
                    <li id="item3"><span></span><a href="#!/page_services">what we do</a></li>
                    <li id="item4"><span></span><a href="#!/page_work">our work</a></li>
                    <li id="item5"><span></span><a href="#!/page_links">links</a></li>
                    <li id="item6"><span></span><a href="#!/page_alert"><span></span>opportunity alert</a></li>
                    <li id="item7"><span></span><a href="#!/page_contacts">contact us</a></li>
                </ul>
          </nav>
```

This seems to work okay except when you scroll down the page, then click another link, then click the link to the previous page you scrolled down on. This returns you to where you were scrolled down previously. I need it to return you to the top of each page when you click on any page link.

Comment: Are you using some kind of CMS?

Answer (score 0):

Just take out the pound sign:

```
<nav class="menu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li id="item1"><span></span><a "javascript:void(0)" href="/">home</a></li>
        <li id="item2"><span></span><a href="/page_about">about us</a></li>
        <li id="item3"><span></span><a href="/page_services">what we do</a></li>
        <li id="item4"><span></span><a href="/page_work">our work</a></li>
        <li id="item5"><span></span><a href="/page_links">links</a></li>
        <li id="item6"><span></span><a href="/page_alert"><span></span>opportunity alert</a></li>
        <li id="item7"><span></span><a href="/page_contacts">contact us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What is the `#!` for anyway? `a href="/page_about"` will work if you have a directory named page_about containing an index.html or similar in the root of your site.

Comment: I see no point in using `#!`.You should simply write `a href="/page_link"`.It works for me every single time.